# Confusion in the position of image coordinates

Tags: image-processing, image

I am struggling to work out how image coordinates are calculated and how to be consistent when finding particular points in an image using these coordinates for further analysis. I don't think it is necessarily a bug, but it makes it tricky to work with and modify images.

This is best shown by the following example.

We make a test image:

```
testIm=ImagePad[Image[IdentityMatrix[15]], {{0, 10}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image: image1]

We then replace one of the pixels (at position 20,3) with the value 2 (so it is easy to find.)

```
testIm2=ReplacePixelValue[testIm, {20, 3} -> 2]
```

[image: image2]

We now try to find the coordinates of this pixel with the value 2.

```
coords=Position[ImageData[testIm2], 2 | 2.]
```

which gives the result `{13,20}`? What is going on here ? How can we be sure of choosing the right pixel values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the following is happening. In the command `ReplacePixelValue` the pixels are numbered in the first coordinate from left to right, then in the second coordinate from bottom to top, i.e. a standard x-y Cartesian system. In the command `Position[ImageData[]]` the result is coordinates numbered firstly from top to bottom, and secondly from left to right. To convert the coordinates then we have in the first system

$(x_i,y_i)$ which gives coordinates $(y_i,1+x_{dim}-x_i)$ where $x_{dim}$ is the dimension of the image in the x-direction in the first coordinate system. I hope this helps other people dealing with this problem